# Should I use an infinitive or "in" plus a gerund?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

Which sentence would be more appropriate?

"Scholars like John Smith are highly qualified *to write* professional essays."

OR

"Scholars like John Smith are highly qualified *in writing* professional essays."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is more appropriate. That said, here's a minor correction:

> Scholars like John Smith are highly qualified to write essays on [whatever the subject happens to be in this case].

"Professional essays" is a bit awkward. An essay is professionally written more or less by definition. You might want to call it something else if it isn't. Unless it's a high school essay, that is, in which case no qualifications are even necessary. Just kidding.